# Issues with Django and VSCode

Tags: css, django, visual-studio-code

I am trying to practice building a website with Django and run into an issue trying to save my VSCode work and update my local browser, but only some things change. When I delete some code in my css file, the vscode is save but the elements in Google Chrome stay the same.

When I inspect the element in the developer tools, the code that was deleted in vscode is still in the elements of the developer after the page is refreshed.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, the problem is with the caching. Your browser is caching the things, thus not getting updated when you change the code. So you should try this;
Go to the site settings in your browser and delete the cache (site data) of your website(represented by the domain, if running locally, it will be 127.0.0.1).